# How many data Firebase.push?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doubt, How many data can Firebase.push in one array name?,For free license account.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an unlimited number of childrens. The number of children is not related to price. The price is related to `Simultaneous connections`, `GB stored` and `GB downloaded`. Please see [Firebase priceing list](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Hope it helps.